# Stack View in iOS

Tags: ios, stack

I have stacked few views separately and horizontally. Now I have selected these stacked views and wish to stack them vertically. But when I press the stack button in stack bar, it is choosing horizontal axis. I can change the  axis to vertical now but that changes the order of stack views and make me work harder in rearranging them in outline.

Is it possible to choose the axis before we press the stack button?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No you can't. Until xcode 8 beta, the *arrange in stack view* tool always chooses the axis based on the current relative position of the views.

Answer (score 1):

If by "stack button" you mean selected "Embed in Stack View" in the task bar, then no, I don't believe there's a way to select horizontal embedding. You can, however, add a horizontal stack view nib to your storyboard first, and then place your arranged subviews inside it.

[image]